# Echo specific part of cURL output?

Tags: php, curl

So I've got this:

```
$pageurl = "http://www.example.com";
$group = $_POST['group'];
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pageurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "group=$group");
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Which returns a web page. What I want to do is display only a certain part of that page, for example a single table. How would I go about that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Use DOMDocument to parse the HTML and get the part you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this  library [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Provided code seems incorrect - before

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "group=$group");`

you should specify

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

to make sure your cURL HTTP POST request is going to be established correctly. (otherwise HTTP GET is default)

To extract parts of returned HTML document, best way is by using **strip_tags() function** http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php, which will clear your code from any parts of HTML you do not want.